# Multiple AZURE Account tenants and a single on-site premises

Tags: azure-networking

- If I am a company with my registered account on AZURE,

  - and I want 2 separate tenants (not subscriptions),

    - that both need to connect to my single on-prem services only - not to each other, then:

      1. do I need 2 site-2site VPNs?
      2. or can we share a single site2site VPN? (I suspect so but cannot find an authoritative source).

Comment: if the company that you own in theory can beam packets from one physical site to another without a direkt link yes, else no. joke aside, you have 3 locations and need from yours connected to two others. i think you understand the point from now ;)

Comment: @djdomi  plain english option  1 or 2? it was a discussion amongst colleagues that could not be resolved as the azure TA was not there.

Comment: what i means is that you need a link to every site from the central

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 site2site VPNs as nothing is shared between tenants.